# XPS 13 9360 DE Bluetooth connection problems and missing module

Tags: drivers, 16.04, bluetooth, dell, xps

on Halloween my brand new XPS 13 9360 DE with Ubuntu 16.04 preinstalled arrived. It's a nice piece of hardware but I got a little problem with the Bluetooth module.

According to my system specifications I got a Killer 1535 built in. This Wifi and Bluetooth combo card should be supported out of the box, but it wont work on my new device:

Description:

After starting Bluetooth and trying to connect to a BT-mouse (tested with MS Arc Touch and Logtech UltraThin) I get an error and afterwards the Bluetooth adapter is missing. No chance to restart this adapter in running system. I have to shutdown and boot system again. Reboot wont bring up the adapter again. After boot the adapter works again.

I figured out, that my chances to get a working connection during session increases if I try to connect after several secs/mins after boot and not directly after boot is finished. But if I reboot the systems with a working connection during a running session the connection is lost and the adapter disappears again.

My Wifi works perfect all the time, so no HW-error I think. Maybe a firmware or driver problem.

uname -a

```
Linux Debby 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg | grep Blue (with failed connection)

```
[    9.144119] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    9.144132] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.144135] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.144137] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.144142] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.151133] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    9.151135] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    9.151136] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    9.151137] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    9.151138] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    9.151138] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    9.151162] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    9.151172] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    9.151173] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    9.525168] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.525171] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.525174] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.541052] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[    9.541055] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[    9.569032] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[   11.280881] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   11.280900] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   11.280911] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   71.461848] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200d tx timeout
```

dmesg | grep Blue (with working connection)

```
[    9.306492] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    9.306508] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.306511] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.306513] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.306518] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.313115] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    9.313119] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    9.313120] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    9.313121] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    9.313122] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    9.313123] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    9.313153] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    9.313167] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    9.313168] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    9.666210] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.666213] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.666217] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.832434] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[    9.832438] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[    9.862956] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[   11.523670] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   11.523686] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   11.523698] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 2937.641365] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff88026e4fc6c0 failed to resubmit (2)
[ 2941.417843] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[ 2941.417845] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[ 2941.446208] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[ 3056.134093] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
[ 3634.798271] Bluetooth: Failed to add device to auto conn whitelist: status 0x0c
[ 3704.448082] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[ 3704.448085] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[ 3704.476165] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
```

lsmod | grep ath

```
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           311296  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

Already tried to replace files from http://www.killernetworking.com/product-support/knowledge-base/17-linux in folder `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0` with no success.

rfkill list

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I am pretty sure it's a software problem.

Driver-Overview

[image]

dmesg --level=err

```
[    9.665577] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   47.730682] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200d tx timeout
```

I realized that firmware-5.bin is necessary, but I don't know where to get it from.

```
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0$ ls -la
insgesamt 2208
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov  2 22:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Jun 24 12:37 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 337204 Nov  2 22:24 board-2.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 337204 Sep 14 15:17 board-2.bin.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   8124 Nov  2 22:24 board.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   8124 Apr 25  2016 board.bin.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 733784 Nov  2 22:24 firmware-4.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 733784 Apr 25  2016 firmware-4.bin.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  79689 Apr 25  2016 notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt
```

linux-firmware version

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
»linux-firmware« ist bereits die neuste Version (1.157.4).
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
```

dmesg | egrep 'ath|firm'

```
[    1.162298] i915_bpo 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/kbl_dmc_ver1.bin failed with error -2
[    1.162302] i915_bpo 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares], disabling runtime power management.
[    9.420323] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    9.422482] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    9.663808] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    9.665571] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    9.665577] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   11.889478] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[   11.889490] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   11.959999] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[   11.960007] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   11.960013] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   11.960017] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   11.998743] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
```

If anyone has an idea of what to do to get my bluetooth working I would be really happy.

---

I got news:

Today I tried to connect my MX Anywhere 2 with the XPS 13 through Linux Mint 18 LiveCD.

```
Linux mint 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The first try to connect the BT-Mouse did not work, but after pairing and turning BT off and on again the mouse worked like a charm. Another try to turn on and off did not lead a worse experience. BT works.

BUT, Wifi did not work out of the box. Maybe I'm right with my suggestion that this error is not related to the hardware but to some driver issues.

linux-firmware version

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
linux-firmware is already the newest version (1.157.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The linux-firmware version is older than my Ubuntu one (1.157.4).

dmesg | grep Blue

```
[   12.688999] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   12.689013] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.689016] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.689019] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.689024] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.709288] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   12.709290] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   12.709292] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   12.709293] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[   12.709294] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   12.709295] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   12.709325] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   12.709337] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[   12.709338] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   12.802844] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[   12.802849] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[   12.846931] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[   13.760703] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.760707] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.760712] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.124429] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.124436] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.124441] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   83.286091] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   83.286099] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[  107.004023] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
```

*HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2* and the following is different from my Ubuntu-log.

dmesg | egrep 'ath|firm'

```
[   12.802849] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[   12.969264] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.216469] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   13.216497] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   13.216501] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   13.298573] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin failed with error -2
[   15.433883] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 1 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[   15.433887] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   18.429768] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   18.499292] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[   18.499297] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   18.499300] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   18.499302] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   18.513946] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
[   23.785440] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   29.785002] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   35.100236] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[   38.099913] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[   44.099597] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   49.418815] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   55.418256] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   70.272857] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[   73.272622] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[   79.272012] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   83.321061] input: Ultrathin Touch Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:4/0005:046D:B00D.0002/input/input11
[   83.321592] hid-generic 0005:046D:B00D.0002: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v7.00 Keyboard [Ultrathin Touch Mouse] on 9c:b6:d0:17:3f:76
[   84.599514] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[   87.599349] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[   93.598688] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  105.269586] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[  108.269297] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[  114.268751] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  119.580246] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[  122.579969] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[  128.579403] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  140.278315] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  146.277754] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  151.593288] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[  154.593739] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[  160.592406] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  163.600169] input: Ultrathin Touch Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:1/0005:046D:B00D.0003/input/input12
[  163.602592] hid-generic 0005:046D:B00D.0003: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v7.00 Keyboard [Ultrathin Touch Mouse] on 9c:b6:d0:17:3f:76
[  175.259049] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  181.258483] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  186.565967] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  192.565410] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  208.263945] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3
[  211.263670] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11
[  217.263147] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  222.578636] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  228.578069] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  230.408519] input: Ultrathin Touch Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:1/0005:046D:B00D.0005/input/input14
[  230.410668] hid-generic 0005:046D:B00D.0005: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v7.00 Keyboard [Ultrathin Touch Mouse] on 9c:b6:d0:17:3f:76
```

lsmod | grep ath

```
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           311296  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

Looks alike my Ubuntu lsmod.

ls -la

```
-rwx------ 1 alexander alexander   8124 Apr 25  2016 board.bin
-rwx------ 1 alexander alexander 733784 Apr 25  2016 firmware-4.bin
-rwx------ 1 alexander alexander  79689 Apr 25  2016 notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt
```

It seems, only board-2.bin is different from my Ubuntu firmware.

Now I'm trying to figure out, why BT works with LM.

Again, if you got some ideas. Please let me know.

Comment: Well, "Hi Girls & Guys" is missing at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to martinec's post I got the answer. If you use XPS 13 9360 with Ubuntu 16.04 preinstalled you only have to add the file **/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf**:

```
sudo su
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf
```

Now Bluetooth works nice, and I got no problem with my MX Anywhere 2 and my Teufel BT Bamster.

Comment: After some days I can tell this worked for me. I send those infos to Dell to fix the problem. Unfortunately I got some BT-issues after hours of testing, but after Shutdown + Boot everything works fine again. It happens around every 10 hours in running system.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help but firmware-5.0.bin and board-2.bin can be found in:

```
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
```

I initially tried to just copy these across to the /hw3.0 directory, but this then took down my WiFi connection and I was forced to undo. Haven't got any further than that - I had other, more serious problems to try and fix.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got contact to the killer support and they told me, that firmware-5.0.bin is not required. Even the error message __could not fetch firmware file__ is not relevant. As you can read my experience with LM Live-CD was good even without firmware-5.0.bin. I think this file is not the reason my bluetooth is not working. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling fixing the same issue installing Debian on a Dell XPS 13 9360, and I've just managed to get everything working.

First, download and setup the firmware as suggested [here](http://www.killernetworking.com/product-support/knowledge-base/17-linux/20-killer-wireless-ac-in-linux-ubuntu-debian):

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
wget http://www.killernetworking.com/support/K1535_Debian/board.bin
wget http://www.killernetworking.com/support/K1535_Debian/firmware-4.bin
sudo echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf
```

If dmesg output is complaining about:

```
bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin failed with error -2
```

do as suggested [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=222626#p1171393):

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/qca
cd /lib/firmware/qca
sudo wget http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/qca/rampatch_00130302.bin
sudo wget http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
sudo wget http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
```

Then, even if `firmware-5.0.bin` is actually not required, you could avoid the error message doing:

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
ln -s firmware-4.bin firmware-5.bin
```

Finally, reboot.

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. But all files are already there but the file __/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf__ is missing. This line solved my problems. Bluetooth now works like a charm.